# How do you boost the Hellstorm missile in Black Ops 3?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

How do you boost the Hellstorm missile in Black Ops 3 on PC?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using default controls:
Shift causes it to speed up;
Right click causes it to slow down;
Left click causes it to spread/track enemies.